# how can I print names in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In this program, how can I print names in each gender in alphabetical order?

```
n = int(input())
names = []
f = []
m = []

for i in list(range(n)):
    temp = input()
    tmplst = temp.split(".")
    str = f"{tmplst[1]} = {tmplst}"
    str = str.replace("[","(")
    str = str.replace("]",")")
    print(str)
    exec(str)
    if tmplst[0] == "m":
        exec(f"m.append({tmplst[1]})")
    elif tmplst[0] == "f":
        exec(f"f.append({tmplst[1]})")
    #exec(f"print({tmplst[1]})")

for i in list(range(len(m))):
    print(f[i][0],f[i][1].capitalize(),f[i][2])

for i in list(range(len(m))):
    print(m[i][0],m[i][1].capitalize(),m[i][2])
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to do it? I don't see anything that relates to ordering/sorting.

Comment: What is the rationale for using `exec()`? Why not simply `m.append(tmplst[1])` instead of `exec(f"m.append({tmplst[1]})")`, for example?

Answer (score 2):

In general you have following options: `sorted()` or `list.sort()` either using `lambda` or using `itemgetter()` which is slightly faster.

Using `sorted()` with `lambda`:

```
your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list_unsorted, key = lambda x: x[<1st index>], x[<2nd key>], x[...])
```

Using `sorted()` with `itemgetter()`:

```
import operator
your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list_unsorted, key = operator.itemgetter(<1st index>, <2nd index>, ...))
```

Using `list.sort()` with `lambda`:

```
your_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[<1st index>], x[<2nd key>], x[...])
```

Using `list.sort()` with `itemgetter()`:

```
import operator
your_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(<1st index>, <2nd index>, ...))
```

---

**Example with**

**- Single sorting:**

```
# sorted() - lambda:
your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list_unsorted, key = lambda x: x[1])

# sorted() - itemgetter():
import operator
your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list_unsorted, key = operator.itemgetter(1))

# list.sort() - lambda:
your_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

# list.sort() - itemgetter():
import operator
your_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

**- Multiple sorting:**

```
# sorted() - lambda:
your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list_unsorted, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

# sorted() - itemgetter():
import operator
your_list_sorted = sorted(your_list_unsorted, key = operator.itemgetter(0, 1))

# list.sort() - lambda:
your_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], x[1])

# list.sort() - itemgetter():
import operator
your_list.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0, 1))
```

Comment: thank you! but with these codes, When I give this input:
4
m.hosSein.python
f.miNa.C
m.aHMad.C ++
f.Sara.java
I get this:
f Sara java
f Mina C
m Ahmad C ++
m Hossein python
But I want to get this output:
f Mina C
f Sara java
m Ahmad C ++
m Hossein python

Comment: So you want to sort 1st for index key 0 then for index key 1?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: Look at my last edit on my answer

Comment: @smartnima if my answer was helpful for you, it would be nice to give me a feedback and also upvote / accept my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ['Elle', 'Miles', 'Kratos', 'Joel', 'Peter', 'Nathan']

print(sorted(data))
```

Comment: how can I sort by name?

Comment: Just add sorted(array)

Comment: i have an arrey like : [(m,Nima,python),(m,mina,c++)] and ... , i want to sort by names in m[anything][1]. please help me!

Comment: there is invalid syntax [()]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max()` built-in function, or also the `sorted()` one.

### Sorted

```
>>> sorted(["La", "Le", "Hen", "Han"])
['Han', 'Hen', 'La', 'Le']
```